# DateTime.UtcNow and GETUTCDATE() discrepancy

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, dapper

Our production server has an issue where C# DateTime.UtcNow doesn't line up with SQL Server's GETUTCDATE() by about 27 seconds:

```
Console.WriteLine("C# UTC Date: " + DateTime.UtcNow);
Console.WriteLine("DB UTC Date: " + Connection.Query<DateTime>("SELECT GETUTCDATE()").Single());
```

---

```
C# UTC Date: 4/12/2015 10:47:54 PM 
DB UTC Date: 4/12/2015 10:48:21 PM
```

Running the same code on my local machine correctly shows the same time.

The time returned when running GETDATE() directly on the product server lines up with the server time.

What might be causing this and how could I go about fixing it?

Comment: ajbeaven: when you say "The time returned when running GETDATE() directly on the product server lines up with the server time." do you mean that `GETDATE()` is also off by 27 seconds, or that it is not off like `GETUTCDATE()` is

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: The system clocks on the two computers are not synced.

Comment: GETUTCDATE() accurately matches the server time (shown in the bottom right on Windows) when the timezone is set to UTC

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The problem isn't that the local and production times show different times, it's that the times are different when running on the _same_ machine.

Comment: They're not the same machine, or you'd get the same time. Check into it, and I think you'll find your production Sql Server is a different computer.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn lol, damn you're right! I forgot what server was the build server!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The machine that is running the C# code and the machine that is running the SQL Server have a difference in the system clocks.

There will always be a slight difference, but a difference as large as this is caused by one or both machines failing to get the correct time from an internet source.

In the Date and Time settings, in the Internet Time tab, you find the settings for getting the time from an internet source, and you will see when the server last managed to get an update. If the time server that is chosen doesn't work properly, choose a different time server.